# Failing unit testing of controller to check successful login in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4

I am testing whether a successful log in happens or not. For that I am checking,

- If successfully logged in
- Application should redirect to dashboard

For that my `controller` looks like this

```
public function loginPost(){

    if (Auth::attempt(array(
        'email'     => Input::get('email'),
        'password'  => Input::get('password')
    ))){
        return Redirect::intended(route('dashboard'));
    }

    return Redirect::route('login')             
                        ->withInput()
                        ->with('errorMessage', 'Failed');
}
```

And my `test` looks like this

```
public function testLoginSuccess(){
     $input = [
         'email'                 => 'xyz@gmail.com',
         'password'              => 'computer'
     ];

     Input::replace($input);

     Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')
           ->with($input)
           ->once()
           ->andReturn(true);

     $this->call('POST', 'login', $input);

     $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('dashboard');
 }
```

Although this works in browser. But while testing, it fails with the message:

> BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_0_Illuminate_Auth_AuthManager::check() does not exist on this mock object

Comment: can you paste your full test class

Comment: @Nirmalz Thapaz looks like there's something off about how you're mocking the `Auth` object - can you post where you do your mocking (or the whole test case file)?

Comment: Like @Leith asked, are you mocking the `Auth` object? [Also, Method does not exist on this mock object laravel mockery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747000/method-does-not-exist-on-this-mock-object-laravel-mockery)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show the definition of your route, but I'm assuming your `login` route is protected by the `guest` before filter. This filter uses `Auth::check()` before dispatching to the route.

In your test, when you call `Auth::shouldReceive()`, that makes the `Auth` facade point to a mocked instance. Since you did not define an expectation on the mocked instance for the `check()` method, you're getting an error.

The easiest solution would be to go ahead and mock the `Auth::check()` method as well, and have it return `false` (to emulate visiting the route while not logged in).

```
public function testLoginSuccess() {
    $input = [
        'email' => 'xyz@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'computer'
    ];

    Input::replace($input);

    // Tell Auth we're not logged in.
    Auth::shouldReceive('check')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(false);

    Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')
        ->with($input)
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(true);

    $this->call('POST', 'login', $input);

    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('dashboard');
}
```

You could also write a second test with `Auth::check()` mocked to return `true` in order to test what happens when you visit your login route while already logged in.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is a functional test not a unit test. There is absolutely no need for you keep mocking classes. You need to write a functional test for this.

If i had to do it, i would do something like this:

- Send post request to login route with username, password, csrf_token etc.
- Assert that page is redirected to a link suppose: `http://localhost/home`

So your test code in Laravel 4.2 will be something like this:

```
    // Update the following code accordingly for your app. 

    $credentials = array(
        'email'      => 'john@example.com',
        'password'   => 'johndoe',
        'csrf_token' => csrf_token()
    );

    $this->withInput( $credentials )
        ->requestAction('POST', 'UserController@postLogin');

    $this->assertRedirection( URL::action('HomeController@getIndex') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747000/method-does-not-exist-on-this-mock-object-laravel-mockery) might help.

---

**As an aside:** I agree with @Raza Mehdi.

I think testing the log-in functionality from a high-level, tests our actual code, rather than mocking out the `Auth` object (a type we don't own).

- Call the log-in route, passing the user credentials.
- Assert that the status is OK.
- Assert that the user is redirected to the dashboard.

In code:

```
 $input = [...];

 $this->call('POST', 'login', $input);

 $this->assertResponseStatus(200);

 $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('dashboard');
```